# How many rows are selected in the select in this update statement

Tags: mysql, sql

```
table_a
"id"    "countries"
"1"     "US,CA"
"2"     "US,CA"
"3"     "US,AU"
"4"     "US,UK"
"5"     "US"

table_b
"id"    "country"   "total"
"1"     "US"        "0"
"2"     "CA"        "0"
"3"     "UK"        "0"
"4"     "AU"        "0"
```

**Sql**

```
update table2 
set total = (
    select count(*) from table1 where FIND_IN_SET(country, countries)
)
WHERE country IN ('US','UK') // Are all other countries counted here or only these?
```

I'm trying to update table_b with data from table_a

The above sql works fine, but how many rows actually get selected when it's run?

The comma separated value is what I supply. So, given `'US','UK'`, will the `select count(id)` part also count for rows containing `'AU','CA'` or will it only count rows for what's supplied in the CSV.

My idea is to run a count only for country codes that I supply via the comma seperated string, and not all.

Do this count all or only what I supply in the CSV string?

[**FIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a237d2/1)

Comment: First thing to try is to create a normalised form of table_a so there is only one country in each row - otherwise SQL is not the best language to do this in

Comment: I cant. The `countries` part is where a user decides his profile is visible. So in the end we do select users where countries in('US'), based on the location of the viewer. So if a user selects ('US','UK'), his profile is visible to only users from the US or UK. That's the idea behind this, instead of creating one row for each country.

Comment: That CSV might be the way he enters the data but that should not be the way it is stored convert it in the save code - this makes the rest of the problem much easier - I meant a row per country and user a user can have several rows one for each country

Comment: It comes from a multiple select from a form. I actually didn't get you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Are all other countries counted here or only these?*

only those you made here `WHERE country IN  ('US','UK')` are counted , other will be 0.

[**demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce66d/1)

Comment: `Other will be 0` meaning they wont be counted at all right?

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Now I can Rest in Peace.

Comment: just try thise `WHERE country IN ('US','CA')` , and this `WHERE country IN ('US')` and this `WHERE country IN ('US','CA','AU')` and you will see that it counted only those mentioned in where

Comment: @jmenezes yes rest in peace :).